# Битрикс: свойство "Справочник" в шаблоне компонента "Новости детально"

Tags: php, веб-программирование, битрикс

Здравствуйте.

Нужно вывести данные из свойства типа "Справочник" (название услуги и ссылку, которая ведет с этого названия) на странице детального просмотра новости. Сейчас имеется свойство типа "Список", оно корректно отображается вот так: http://prntscr.com/a3xykc Нужно, чтобы услуги стали кликабельны. Мне кажется, "Справочник" выполнит эту задачу.

Код вывода свойств в шаблоне детального просмотра новости такой:

```
<?foreach($arResult["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"] as $pid=>$arProperty):?> 

<b><?=$arProperty["NAME"]?></b>:&nbsp; 
<?if(is_array($arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"])):?> 
<?=implode("&nbsp;/&nbsp;", $arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"]);?> 
<?else:?> 
<?=$arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"];?> 
<?endif?> 
<br /> 
<?endforeach?>
```

Но он не позволяет отобразить вновь созданное поле со свойством типа "Справочник". Причем остальные поля тоже пропадают, если это свойство активно.

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу. Возможно я ошибаюсь относительно "Справочника" и стоит попробовать другой тип. Какой тип решит мою задачу и как решить вопрос с кодом в иных случаях?

Спасибо.

Comment: что хранится в справочнике, покажите часть таблички, и распечатайте массив, что содержит сейчас свойство. тяжело помочь вслепую

Comment: Вот часть компонента детального описания новости, ответственная за вывод свойств:

<?foreach($arResult["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"] as $pid=>$arProperty):?>

 <b><?=$arProperty["NAME"]?></b>:&nbsp;
  <?if(is_array($arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"])):?>
   <?=implode("&nbsp;/&nbsp;", $arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"]);?>
  <?else:?>
   <?=$arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"];?>
  <?endif?>
  <br />
 <?endforeach>

В справочнике должно быть несколько опций на выбор, например

Монтаж
Печать
Доставка

и, соответственно, ссылки с этих слов:

/montage/
/print/
/delivery/